# Use WebAPI2 in SharePoint 2013 project

Tags: 2013, development, wcf

in the past i have created WCF Services and used them in my SharePoint 2013 projects. I was very easy adding a new definition insise the ISAPI folder an after that to define the Interface and the service itself.

But not i have created a new SharePoint 2013 project and tried to add a new WebAPI Controller. But this is not possible.

Hs someone already used WebAPI 2 in an SP 2013 project and give me guidance on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. I found the following post which explains an implementation but i would do it in this project the old wcf way.

https://melcher.it/2012/12/signalr-in-sharepoint-2013-the-real-time-web-is-coming/